# Why msbuild compiles both in Debug and in Release when just the Release is requested in a certain scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am building two solutions in Release configuration. However, the second solution rebuilds some projects in Debug!

I was able to reduce the test case to a bare minimum. It contains 4 files - 2 sln and 2 csproj files.

Here they are:

**DataSvc.sln**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28010.2048
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Common", "Common\Common.csproj", "{04455D86-A7A4-41E5-B3ED-B0BC65EAFDFD}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Compensation.Data", "Compensation.Data\Compensation.Data.csproj", "{04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {04455D86-A7A4-41E5-B3ED-B0BC65EAFDFD}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {04455D86-A7A4-41E5-B3ED-B0BC65EAFDFD}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {04455D86-A7A4-41E5-B3ED-B0BC65EAFDFD}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {04455D86-A7A4-41E5-B3ED-B0BC65EAFDFD}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {9ED7ECEC-075D-486A-B3F6-9E80EED49AEF}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

**Main.sln**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28010.2026
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Compensation.Data", "Compensation.Data\Compensation.Data.csproj", "{04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {6FBE2C7C-DCEA-4F88-BF8E-FF4927DEFBE5}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

**Common\Common.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{04455D86-A7A4-41E5-B3ED-B0BC65EAFDFD}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Xyz.Common</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Xyz.Common</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <OutputPath>Bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Compensation.Data.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{04DF77A2-912B-40B7-B398-E9558519CAEE}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Compensation.Data</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Compensation.Data</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <OutputPath>Bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Common.csproj">
      <Project>{04455d86-a7a4-41e5-b3ed-b0bc65eafdfd}</Project>
      <Name>Common</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Things to note:

1. The `Compensation.Data` project is loaded both in DataSvc.sln and Main.sln
2. The `Compensation.Data` project references the `Common` project as a project, not DLL, even though it is not found in `Main.sln`

The problem - when compiling the two solutions in **Release**, Main.sln builds `Common` in **Debug**!

Please, observe:

```
C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]> git clean -qdfX
C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]> Test-Path .\Common\bin\Debug
False
C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]> msbuild .\DataSvc.sln /v:m /nowarn:CS2008 /nologo /p:Configuration=Release
  Common -> C:\work\MSBuildBug\Common\Bin\Release\Xyz.Common.dll
  Compensation.Data -> C:\work\MSBuildBug\Compensation.Data\Bin\Release\Compensation.Data.dll
C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]> Test-Path .\Common\bin\Debug
False
C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]> msbuild .\Main.sln /v:m /nowarn:CS2008 /nologo /p:Configuration=Release
  Common -> C:\work\MSBuildBug\Common\Bin\Debug\Xyz.Common.dll
  Compensation.Data -> C:\work\MSBuildBug\Compensation.Data\Bin\Release\Compensation.Data.dll
C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]> Test-Path .\Common\bin\Debug
True
C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]> dir .\Common\bin\Debug


    Directory: C:\work\MSBuildBug\Common\bin\Debug


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/18/2020   1:24 AM           3584 Xyz.Common.dll
-a----        2/18/2020   1:24 AM           7680 Xyz.Common.pdb


C:\work\MSBuildBug [master]>
```

This works like this both in VS 2017 and VS 2019.

What am I missing here? Why does it compile in Debug at all?

Comment: `Main.sln` has only `Compensation.Data` project, but has `Common` project reference. Have you tried to add `Common` to `Main.sln` as well?

Comment: I am pretty certain it would work, but my use case is different. The actual solution has ~100 projects and some reference others outside of the solution. I do not understand why this scenario does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here - https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/5116#issuecomment-584211463

Setting this (e.g. in Directory.Build.props) resolves the issue:

```
<ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform>false</ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform>
```